# How to get column names in an oracle select statement

Tags: oracle, cx-oracle

To get the column names in a `mysql` or `mssql` connection I'm able to do the following:

```
>>> cursor.execute('select * from table)
>>> [item[0] for item in cursor.description]
[u'provider', u'title', u'date', u'apple_id', u'country', u'genre', u'sales_in_usd']
```

How would I get the column names from an Oracle cursor?

Comment: check this link: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2109642600346678459

Answer (score 0):

The code you have above works just fine with cx_Oracle (the driver that enables access to Oracle databases) since it follows the Python Database API!